# Build gets stuck on "Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)" in flutter run

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

This is my first app created using Flutter. I am constantly getting this error.

Setup version:

```
PS D:\> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

The issue is the build gets stuck on the line

> Starting gradle daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

```
flutter create myapp
flutter run -v

PS D:\FlutterProjects\myapp> flutter run -d 73e557b65f35 -v
    [  +59 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [ +178 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [   +5 ms] f139b11009aeb8ed2a3a3aa8b0066e482709dde3
    [   +1 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
    [ +213 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
    [   +1 ms] v1.12.13+hotfix.9-0-gf139b1100
    [  +16 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [  +94 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [        ] origin/stable
    [        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [  +61 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    [ +160 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [ +121 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [   +1 ms] stable
    [ +271 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
    [ +112 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
    [   +1 ms] List of devices attached
               4a635a82               device product:10or_D model:D device:10or_D transport_id:4
               73e557b65f35           device product:laurel_sprout model:Mi_A3 device:laurel_sprout transport_id:7
    [  +43 ms] C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 73e557b65f35 shell getprop
    [ +205 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [  +13 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
    [  +26 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +8 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
    [ +384 ms] Generating
    D:\FlutterProjects\myapp\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
    [  +77 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
    [ +134 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on Mi A3 in debug mode...
    [  +36 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 73e557b65f35 shell -x logcat -v
    time -t 1
    [ +139 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 73e557b65f35 shell -x
    logcat -v time -t 1
    [   +8 ms] --------- beginning of main
               04-05 22:17:22.545 V/APM_AudioPolicyManager(  682): AudioPolicyManager:setRecordSilenced(uid:10029,
               silenced:1)
    [  +29 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
    [   +5 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 73e557b65f35 logcat -v time -T
    04-05 22:17:22.545
    [ +101 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                        Version 28.0.3-5475833
                        Installed as C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
    [  +15 ms] executing: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
    [  +88 ms] Building APK
    [  +88 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    [  +50 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
    [  +13 ms] Using gradle from D:\FlutterProjects\myapp\android\gradlew.bat.
    [  +27 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
    [ +227 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
    [   +6 ms] openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
               OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)
               OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b01, mixed mode)
    [  +10 ms] executing: [D:\FlutterProjects\myapp\android\] D:\FlutterProjects\myapp\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true
    -Ptarget=D:\FlutterProjects\myapp\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root
    -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 assembleDebug
    [+4299 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not an issue at all. For your first app, running it on the emulator takes a considerably long period of time. I've a decently fast machine and it took around 20-22 minutes to launch the app on the emulator.

From the `flutter run -v` command you can see that it has got a lot of stuff to download and set up, therefore even if your internet has good speed, be patient. It will be built.

Also, don't fret it much. After this initial build, the subsequent builds will be pretty fast.

Comment: yes I came to know my gradle file was missing and it was around 150 mbs which took time.